# Which scheduling techniques VEINS framework is using ? ( scheduling algorithm)

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am on a graduation project with the title "scheduling techniques in VANET", and I need to know which algorithm is used in VEINS , how messages are scheduled in the queue? using multi level or priority based algorithm or another algorithm , I need to know where exactly are implemented on the framework code C++ .

Answer (score 3):

Veins is a toolkit for vehicular network simulation. It includes models of lower layer protocols (phy/mac), so you can use it for implementing a higher layer protocol of your choice. No higher layer protocols are included with Veins 4.6, so the answer to your question "which scheduling techniques are used" is likely "whichever you want to implement".

Comment: thank you Christoph Sommer put  In my project I need to simulate VANETt messages scheduling  using DS algorithm (deadline and size are the parameters in each message received in the queue) where I should put the algorithm in veins I don't know how to create a new protocol.

Comment: This is a different question. If you feel your question has been answered, please close this one and open a new one.